# why Xcode refers to nonexistent file?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, svn, versions

I'm using version control "Versions" SVN for Mac.
After updating, Xcode begun to show this error

```
clang: error: no such file or directory:'/Users/ThisUser/Documents/Applic/trunk/ios/Applic1.0/CheckBoxClass/FCheckBox.m' 
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Truly, I deleted FCheckBox.h and FCheckBox.m files from directory, and all references to it. Also deleted them from SVN (via bash). But despite that the error appears..
(tried also to clean)

Anybody knows what the problem is?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you deleted the files in compiler sources?

If you delete it from the project navigator, it will not be deleted in compiler sources.

Go to `Targets-> Build Phases->Compiler Sources`.
Check for the file name. If the file has a name that's colored red, select the file and delete it.

Comment: If you get satisfied answer you should accept the answer by clicking the tick mark on left side of the answer

Comment: Thank you. Actually my friend Commited and I updated successfully! But I will take a note of this info!